# SQL Server Query for average value over a date period

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @SampleOrderTable TABLE
                          (
                               pkPersonID INT,
                               OrderDate DATETIME,
                               Amount NUMERIC(18, 6)
                          )

INSERT INTO @SampleOrderTable (pkPersonID, OrderDate, Amount) 
VALUES (1, '12/10/2019', '762.84'),
       (2, '11/10/2019', '886.32'),
       (3, '11/9/2019', '10245.00')
```

How do I select the the last 4 days prior to `OrderDate` and the average Amount over that period?

So result data would be:

```
pkPersonID   Date             Amount
------------------------------------
    1        '12/7/2019'     190.71
    1        '12/8/2019'     190.71
    1        '12/9/2019'     190.71
    1        '12/10/2019'    190.71
    2        '12/7/2019'     221.58
    2        '12/8/2019'     221.58
    2        '12/9/2019'     221.58
    2        '12/10/2019'    221.58
    3        '11/6/2019'    2561.25
    3        '11/7/2019'    2561.25
    3        '11/8/2019'    2561.25
    3        '11/9/2019'    2561.25
```

Comment: I am baffled by the question.  First, you are only selecting *three* days before the order date.  Second, you seem to just be copying the order value, but are using the phrase "average amount over that period".  I don't think your sample data really conveys your problem.  I would suggest you ask a *new* question with a better explanation and sample data.  What happens when someone has multiple orders, for instance?

Comment: Baffled also about how PersonID 2 seems to time traveled from Nov 10 to Dec 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try with the following approach, using `DATEADD()`, windowed `COUNT()` and `VALUES()` table value constructor:

Table:

```
DECLARE @SampleOrderTable TABLE (
   pkPersonID INT,
   OrderDate DATETIME,
   Amount NUMERIC(18, 6)
)
INSERT INTO @SampleOrderTable (pkPersonID, OrderDate, Amount) 
VALUES (1, '20191210', '762.84'),
       (2, '20191210', '886.32'),
       (3, '20191109', '10245.00')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   t.pkPersonID,
   DATEADD(day, -v.Day, t.OrderDate) AS [Date],
   CONVERT(numeric(18, 6), Amount / COUNT(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY t.pkPersonID)) AS Amount
FROM @SampleOrderTable t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3)) v(Day)
ORDER BY t.pkPersonID, [Date]
```

Result:

```
pkPersonID  Date                Amount
1           07/12/2019 00:00:00 190.710000
1           08/12/2019 00:00:00 190.710000
1           09/12/2019 00:00:00 190.710000
1           10/12/2019 00:00:00 190.710000
2           07/12/2019 00:00:00 221.580000
2           08/12/2019 00:00:00 221.580000
2           09/12/2019 00:00:00 221.580000
2           10/12/2019 00:00:00 221.580000
3           06/11/2019 00:00:00 2561.250000
3           07/11/2019 00:00:00 2561.250000
3           08/11/2019 00:00:00 2561.250000
3           09/11/2019 00:00:00 2561.250000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sql functions like AVG, DATEADD and GETDATE.

```
SELECT AVG(Amount) as AverageAmount
FROM @SampleOrderTable
WHERE OrderDate >= DATEADD(DAY, -4, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @SampleOrderTable TABLE (
  pkPersonID INT,
  OrderDate DATETIME,
  Amount NUMERIC(18, 6)
);

INSERT INTO @SampleOrderTable
  (pkPersonID, OrderDate, Amount) 
VALUES
  (1, '12/20/2019', 762.84),
  (2, '12/20/2019', 886.32),
  (3, '12/20/2019', 10245.00),
  (4, '12/19/2019', 50.00),
  (5, '12/19/2019', 100.00),
  (6, '09/01/2019', 200.00),
  (7, '09/01/2019', 300.00),
  (8, '12/15/2019', 400.00),
  (9, '12/15/2019', 500.00),
  (10, '09/02/2019', 150.00),
  (11, '09/02/2019', 1100.00),
  (12, '09/02/2019', 1200.00),
  (13, '09/02/2019', 1300.00),
  (14, '09/02/2019', 1400.00),
  (15, '09/02/2019', 1500.00);

SELECT OrderDate,AVG(Amount) AS Average_Value
FROM @SampleOrderTable
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(OrderDate AS DATETIME), CAST(GETDATE() AS Datetime)) <= 4
GROUP BY OrderDate;
```

Comment: You also could have created a [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e6d061fd75fb4f73260c4eec65132b79) 